# Setting permisison of log file in rsyslog configuration

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog

There is an option in rsyslog configuration to set the permission & ownership of the log file created.

```
$fileOwner sv
if $programname contains 'my_process' then /var/log/my_process.log
```

If the log file (`/var/log/my_process.log`) is not present, the file will be created with owner as "sv" user. [Manual](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omfile.html)

But this will change the setting for all the forthcoming files as well.

Is there a way to the set the permission of only a particular log file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a way that works. After the configuration, reset the variable back to its default value.

```
$fileOwner sv
if $programname contains 'my_process' then /var/log/my_process.log
$fileOwner root
```